# Sending Emails With phpmailer From A php Project?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i want to send emails with phpmailer.

for doing that i searched google and i found the blow link :

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

so i download their libraries from here (by download link in their site , php 4-5):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php4/0.90/

after that i refer to this example : (mean advanced using smtp)

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleasmtp

```
<?php
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}

?>
```

but i could n't find class.phpmailer.php file for this line -> require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');  from dowloaded file.

did i miss something?

would u plz help me for that?

best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "../" means "one directory level higher". That means that it should look for the file class.phpmailer.php in the directory one higher than that where this script is executing from. If that's not where you saved class.phpmailer.php relative to your code, then adjust the path.

Comment: thanks 4 answer / i understand your meaning / but there is no class.phpmailer.php file at all/plz download that project and see what am i saying! / should i download it from another location ?

Comment: That example is for "PHPMailer for PHP4" download, not "PHPMailer for PHP5" which has not been updated in 10 years. I recommend you NOT use that. Heck, I recommend you not use PHPMailer at all -- try SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
                <?php
            include "/home/tnehme/public_html/smtpmail/classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

            $mail = new PHPMailer(); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

            try {
              $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
              $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
              $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
              $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
              $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
              $mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
              $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
              $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
              $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
              $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
              $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
              $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
              $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
              $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
              $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
              $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
              $mail->Send();
              echo "Message Sent OK\n";
            } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
              echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
            }

            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using PHPMailer with the 5.5.10 and its working really well.

It was very easy to get up and running. Copy files into a directory (alongside your PHP files)

'include' it in your script... and use the example code they give you as a basis for your email.

To get the files visit:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

good luck.

I also here good things about SwiftMailer.